# Change UICollectionView cell size on press - Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I am trying to build this view: https://dribbble.com/shots/3812962-iPhone-X-Todo-Concept

We can see that when the user swipes up on a cell, rather than displaying a new view, the cell expands and displays more information. How can I achieve this in Swift? I use a UICollectionView to house all the cells. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven’t been able to find an answer on StackOverflow that helps with advanced animations like this. However, I think that once the cell is clicked/swiped up on, the cell expands and then a new UIViewController is presented.

There’s a handy CocoaPods library that may help you with this. You can check it out [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Hero). (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Hero)